# Как сравнить значения массива в массиве.php

Tags: php, массивы, laravel

[image: пример массива]

Всем добрый день! Есть такой массив с массивами, мне нужно исключить из него повторения дат, и выбрать только массив с последней датой, пытался сделать через foreach, в котором сравниваю прошлую итерацию цикла с текущей, но ничего к дельному это не привело. Можете помочь?
P.S Пишу на Laravel.

Comment: А вы не можете при формирования массива даты использовать в качестве ключа?

Comment: в принципе могу, только потому придется обратно менять ключ значение

Comment: Зачем потом что-то менять? Вы можете оставить структуру массива как есть, просто ключи будут не `1`, `2`, `3` , а `17-May-20`, `18-May-20`, `19-May-20`. Но даты при этом дублироваться не будут

Comment: Проблема в том что дата хранится в формате даты, а array_flip с датами не будет работать, только со строкой

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function compare_date($a, $b)
{
    return strtotime($b[0]) - strtotime($a[0]);
}

function arr_unique($array, $key)
{
   $temp = [];
   foreach ($array as $k => $v) {
       if (!isset($temp[$array[$k][$key]]))
       $temp[$array[$k][$key]] =& $array[$k];
   }
   return array_values($temp);
}

usort($arr, 'compare_date');

var_dump(arr_unique($arr,'0'));
```

[PHP Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/abf8dcfdd535ae236157dc792f275a01c50bffcc)

**upd.** *первый эл-т массива, надеюсь, не надо показывать как "извлекать"*

Comment: а для чего это ?

function compare_date($a, $b)
{
    return strtotime($b[0]) - strtotime($a[0]);
}

Comment: А если мне нужно вернуть последний элемент массива, а не первый?

Comment: @АлексейГаврилов Слов нет... " и выбрать только массив с последней датой" - это ответ на оба ваших вопроса.